# ASUS Notebook freezes and fans spin fast

Tags: windows, asus-laptop

The only solution is to force the shut down. I opened the computer and checked if the fans were dirty but that does not seem to be the problem.

I tried waiting for a moment, but the computer continuous in that state.

The model is a F541U, 8GB of RAM, Windows 10 64-bit, i7-6500U 2.5 GHz, 1TB HDD

The issue comes usually, when I close a game and switch in to another app.

Any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What ASUS model is it? What are you doing when it freezes? Does anything happen if you leave the computer in that state for a while? What OS are you using?

Comment: I edited the post. If I leave the computer like that for a while, nothing happens.